# Appending 2 dataframes with having duplicates without removing the duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to append prediction to my original data which is:

```
product_id          date      views  wishlists  cartadds    orders  order_units gmv score
mp000000000001321   01-09-2022  0    0           0           0        0        0    0
mp000000000001321   02-09-2022  0    0           0           0        0        0    0
mp000000000001321   03-09-2022  0    0           0           0        0        0    0
mp000000000001321   04-09-2022  0    0           0           0        0        0    0
```

I have sequence length of [1,3] and each for each sequence length I have prediction. I want to add those prediction to my original data so that my output is like this:

```
product_id          date      views  wishlists  cartadds    orders  order_units gmv score prediction  sequence_length
mp000000000001321   01-09-2022  0    0           0           0        0        0    0      5.75          1
mp000000000001321   01-09-2022  0    0           0           0        0        0    0      5.88          3
mp000000000001321   02-09-2022  0    0           0           0        0        0    0      5.88          3
mp000000000001321   03-09-2022  0    0           0           0        0        0    0      5.88          3
```

I have tried the following:

```
df1 = df_batch.head(sequence_length)
dfff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(predictions_dict, orient='index')
dfff.index.names = ['product_id']
merged_df = df1.merge(dfff, on='product_id')


merged_df.to_csv('data_prediction'+str(sequence_length)+'.csv', index_label='product_id')
```

but this only saves the data of last product_id which was sent and it saves for each sequence length in a different csv. I want everything to be in 1 csv instead. How do that?

Edit: sample predictions_dict:

```
{'mp000000000001321': {'sequence_length': 1, 'prediction': 5.75}}

{'mp000000000001321': {'sequence_length': 3, 'prediction': 5.88}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible example? What is in `predictions_dict`?

Comment: Added predictions_dict

Comment: Can you make your example inputs minimal? At the moment the dictionary doesn't match the values in the dataset. We need to have a complete **minimal** example to demonstrate a potential solution in a reproducible way.

Comment: You will find me annoying, but the provided dictionary has duplicated keys, so this drops the duplicates. Try to see for yourself.

Comment: I know, I'm looking for a way, as for each product_id I'm predicting on different sequence_length, and I want to append the results for each sequence_length

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a fix

```
df1 = df_batch[df_batch['product_id'] == product_id].iloc[:sequence_length]
dfff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(predictions_dict, orient='index')
dfff.index.names = ['product_id']
merged_df = df1.merge(dfff, on='product_id')
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, merged_df], ignore_index=True)
```

This way I'm able to get the desired output for unique product id's